# Raspberry Pi 3b and and Sunfounder KiT 1.0

Tags: gpio, pi-3, compatibility

I have RPI-3b and Sunfounder kit 1.0, and 40 pin GPIO extension board and cable.

Is it possible to use these device and components together?

PS: Sunfounder kit 1.0 is for RPI 1,2(b+).

Comment: I believe the GPIO layout of the Pi 3, Pi 2 and B+ is the same, so in that sense it should work.

Comment: I tried project from the URI: https://www.sunfounder.com/learn/category/Sensor-Kit-v1-0-for-Raspberry-Pi.html and it did not work.I just changed the GPIO pin numbers in C code. I through it might be compatibility issue.

Comment: Could you try the project with the GPIO pin numbers left as they were?

Comment: Actually the project code was for 26 pin GPIO extension. There was a difference between pin numbers. I could not find 0 and 1 GPIO numbers from 40 pin GPIO extension board. That was the problem.

Comment: I am sure there has to be some sort of conversion chart between the 26 pin GPIO and the 40 pin GPIO layout.

Answer (score 1):

The Pi3B will operate in exactly the same manner as a Pi2B, Pi B+, Pi A+, and Pi Zero when used with the Sunfounder kit.